# Unable to print values for Area and Perimeter inside my formatted column

Tags: java, printf

This is my code so far for a program in which I am supposed to print the area and perimeter of rectangles using all the possible combinations of lengths and widths from 1 to 10. I basically set up the table, but don't know how to put the area and perimeter values in the table.

```
public class Project_6_7 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int area;
    int perimeter;

    System.out.println("                             Length");
    System.out.printf("%10s%5s%5s%5s%5s%5s%5s%5s%5s%5s" , "1" , "2" , "3", "4", "5" , "6" , "7", "8", "9", "10");

    for (int width = 1; width <= 10; width++){
        System.out.println();
        if (width == 5){
            System.out.print("Width  " + width);
        }else
            System.out.print("       " + width);
        for (int length = 1; length <= 10; length++){
            area = width * length;
            perimeter = 2 * (length + width);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: use a `System.out.print` inside your inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Inside you `for-loop` print out the area and perimeter on the same line, and also initialize your area and perimeter. You can use an 2D array for a better view.
like this:

```
    for (int length = 1; length <= 10; length++){
            area = width * length;
           // perimeter = 2 * (length + width);
            System.out.print(area +"  ");
        }
```

You'll have to create another table for perimeter.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally to pretty print, you should have different tables for both *area* and *perimeter* in your case. Anyway, I played around with `printf` and tried to minimize the lines of code involved to just make it look better and came up with this, have added comments to why I used what -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("%32s", "Length"); // approx half of total chars ((5*10 + 7)/2)
    System.out.printf("%7s", ""); // why 7? 5 char 'width' + 1 space + 1 digit
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        //row marking
        System.out.printf("\n%7s", i == 0 ? "" : i == 5 ? "Width " + i : i); //this i would be width eventually

        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            int area = i * j; // here j would be the corresponding length
            System.out.printf("%5s", i == 0 ? j : area); // this is just the area(1 parameter)
        }
    }
}
```

You can move the logic to a method which can be generic enough to accept a parameter and print the table for you. Something on the lines of ENUM to what you want to print the table for (input to the method) based on which you can do the manipulation part.

Answer (score 0):

I swapped up a bit of the code so there was more room in the table for the information you wanted, and took the liberty of adding an extra line for each rectangle. There's also a stagger due to single digit values vs double digit values that I'm still working on, but this should work for the time being.

```
public class PersonalRectanglePrinting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] width = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int[] length = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int[][] areas = new int[width.length][length.length];
        int[][] perimeters = new int[width.length][length.length];

        for(int currentWidth : width) {
            for(int currentLength : length) {
                areas[currentWidth - 1][currentLength - 1] = 
                        currentWidth * currentLength;
                perimeters[currentWidth - 1][currentLength - 1] = 
                        2 * (currentWidth + currentLength);
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("%39s\n", "Length");
        System.out.printf("%10s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s\n" , "1" , "2" , "3",
                "4", "5" , "6" , "7", "8", "9", "10");

        for(int currentWidth : width) {
            if(currentWidth == 5) {
                System.out.printf("Width ");
            } else {
                System.out.printf("      ");
            }

            System.out.printf("%s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s\n", currentWidth, 
                    "A: " + areas[currentWidth - 1][0], 
                    "A: " + areas[currentWidth - 1][1], 
                    "A: " + areas[currentWidth - 1][2], 
                    "A: " + areas[currentWidth - 1][3], 
                    "A: " + areas[currentWidth - 1][4], 
                    "A: " + areas[currentWidth - 1][5], 
                    "A: " + areas[currentWidth - 1][6], 
                    "A: " + areas[currentWidth - 1][7], 
                    "A: " + areas[currentWidth - 1][8], 
                    "A: " + areas[currentWidth - 1][9]);
            System.out.printf("%13s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s\n",
                    "P: " + perimeters[currentWidth - 1][0], 
                    "P: " + perimeters[currentWidth - 1][1], 
                    "P: " + perimeters[currentWidth - 1][2], 
                    "P: " + perimeters[currentWidth - 1][3], 
                    "P: " + perimeters[currentWidth - 1][4], 
                    "P: " + perimeters[currentWidth - 1][5], 
                    "P: " + perimeters[currentWidth - 1][6], 
                    "P: " + perimeters[currentWidth - 1][7], 
                    "P: " + perimeters[currentWidth - 1][8], 
                    "P: " + perimeters[currentWidth - 1][9]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also working on fixing up those extra lines of code. Hope this helped a bit though!